# Is there a way to find out what a bluetooth LE device listens to?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, decompiling

I have a bluetooth LE device that is powered by its developer's app.
Sadly it is not maintained anymore and therefore I intend to rewrite the app from scratch.

Additionally it is not possible to pair to the device. It only listens to BLE.

Is it possible in any way to find out, how the device is being controlled?

I tried to decompile the code via JADX but since the manufacturer is chinese and decompilation already comes with its own problems, I thought if it would be possible to find it out without this  procedure. [(GitHub)App-Decompiled-Code](https://github.com/Drackrath/iYouDecompiled/) [(External)Original-APK-Download-Page](http://www.anshunkang.com.cn/app/iyou/iyou.html)

Answer (score 0):

It depends what the device is really. There are number of profiles/services defined in the Bluetooth standard. If the device uses one of them then you could design from the specification rather than the device/app.

A good place to start is to use a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) to explore the device. Find out the UUIDs of the services and characteristics and compare it to the assigned 16-bit UUIDs values on https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/

If it has a [custom BLE profile/service](https://www.novelbits.io/uuid-for-custom-services-and-characteristics/) then you can still use the nRF Connect app to explore it. If it is not obvious how to access the data or what commands need to be sent, then looking at the [HCI logs on the phone](https://medium.com/@charlie.d.anderson/how-to-get-the-bluetooth-host-controller-interface-logs-from-a-modern-android-phone-d23bde00b9fa) after using the developer's app might be helpful.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your Reply! I was researching a little bit and nRF Connect didnt help very much, but that second approach with the HCI logs and Wireshark led me to the conclusion: 
`Sent Vendor Command 0x0154 (opcode 0xFD54)` Leads to:
`16-bit UUID for Members 0xFD54 Qingdao Haier Technology Co., Ltd` 
and `​0x0154 ​Pebble Technology`
Where can I find BLE Documentation for controlling Devices with this UUID and company tech?

Comment: It is more helpful on this site if you update your question with any additional information rather than put it in the comments. There is a little bit more information you need to find before knowing which documentation to look at. You need to find the list primary service UUIDs on the device. You will also need to know which  Characteristic UUIDs are under each of those service UUIDs